# Child of div to be the same height minus top and bottom paddding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking to set the height of a child divs to be the same as the parent divs. As it stands the divs gets larger and larger as the page resizes. It's for a search result so there are lots of the same blocks of code.

```
function legendHeight() {
    $result = $('.search-result');
    $resultHeight = $result.height(); 
    if($result.find('.legend-lead').length != 0) {
      $(this).children('.legend').height($resultHeight);
    }
};


$(window).load(function () {
    equalheight('.search-result');
    legendHeight();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    equalheight('.search-result');
    legendHeight();
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle to show what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/o0nzo47k/

Although the boxes should resize onload (not why that is not working), if you resize the window you will see the blue divs get taller and taller.

Comment: So, Whats the problem?

Comment: why are you not using css for it

Comment: How about `height : 100%`

Comment: It needs to work across all browsers and from whats I understand 100% height doesn't

Comment: @Satpal The problem is that the child divs get larger and larger as you resize the window. It seems to be adding the height of all child elements. I'll try and setup a JSFiddle now

Comment: @Satpal I have now updated the question.

Comment: In my opinion,resize event should only change the top level dom size.Children nodes can determine size with css.

Comment: display:block, box-sizing:border-box, height:100%, height: calc() Some combination of these should make it less of a headache.

Comment: with pure CSS this should be simple.. why are you taking javascript route? any reason?

Comment: @Reddy - I honestly though IE8 and potentially 9 didn't handle the 100% height. Not to worry, I'll use the CSS route. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1):

OK here is your example working fine https://jsfiddle.net/3wnLeoyd/

the inner `divs` height(`.legend-lead-key` and `.legend-lead-address`) I handled them using css only and I used jquery on the outer height ( to make the height of each div is the same )

The css :

```
.search-result{
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding: 20px;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: 2.34741784%;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.search-result:nth-child(3n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.legend-lead{
  display:table;  
}

.legend-lead-key {
  background: blue;
  border-right: 1px solid #c7cada;
  display:table-cell;
}

.legend-lead-address{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

js :

```
function equalheight(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.search-result .legend-lead').height('auto');
    $('.search-result').each(function(){
    if($(this).height()>=maxHeight){
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  })
  return maxHeight;
}

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.search-result .legend-lead').height(equalheight());
})

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.search-result .legend-lead').height(equalheight());
})
```